# Running two programs each having infinite loops in parallel

Tags: c, loops, for-loop, parallel-processing

I have a speech recognition program which is a continuous based speech recognition (source: CMU SPHINX) 
It contatins a infinite for loop which can be shown as below;

```
for (;;) {
wait for start of next utterance;
decode utterance until silence of at least 1 sec observed;
print utterance result;
}


// Partial code where i tried to do the both operation -----

recognize_from_microphone()
{
ad_rec_t *ad;
int16 adbuf[4096];
int32 k, ts, rem;
char const *hyp;
char const *uttid;
cont_ad_t *cont;
char word[256];
int counter_correct;
int Nummer1, Nummer2, Nummer3, Nummer4,id;
int token = 500;
struct sockaddr_in my_addr, cli_addr[2],cli_temp;
int sockfd;
socklen_t slen[2],slen_temp;
slen[0]=sizeof(cli_addr[0]);
slen[1]=sizeof(cli_addr[1]);
slen_temp = sizeof(cli_temp);
char buf[BUFLEN];
int clients = 0;
int client_port[2];

if ((ad = ad_open_dev(cmd_ln_str_r(config, "-adcdev"),
(int) cmd_ln_float32_r(config,
"-samprate"))) == NULL)
E_FATAL("Failed to open audio device\n");

/* Initialize continuous listening module */
if ((cont = cont_ad_init(ad, ad_read)) == NULL)
E_FATAL("Failed to initialize voice activity detection\n");
if (ad_start_rec(ad) &lt; 0)
E_FATAL("Failed to start recording\n");
if (cont_ad_calib(cont) &lt; 0)
E_FATAL("Failed to calibrate voice activity detection\n");

printf("\n\n");
system("setterm -bold on");



if ((sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_UDP))==-1)
{
    printf("test\n");
    err("socket");
    }else{
    printf("Server : Socket() successful\n");
}
bzero(&my_addr, sizeof(my_addr));
my_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
my_addr.sin_port = htons(PORT);
my_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);

if (bind(sockfd, (struct sockaddr* ) &my_addr, sizeof(my_addr))==-1)
{
    err("bind");
    }else{
    printf("Server : bind() successful\n");
}

for (;;) {


    //receive
    printf("Receiving...\n");
    if (recvfrom(sockfd, buf, BUFLEN, 0, (struct sockaddr*)&cli_temp, &slen_temp)==-1)  {
        err("recvfrom()");
    }
    if (clients==0) {
        cli_addr[0] = cli_temp;
        //get client 0 port
        client_port[0] = ntohs(cli_addr[0].sin_port);
        clients++;
        printf("Client 0 connected. Port: %d\n",client_port[0]);
        sendto(sockfd, "You are the first client.", 24, 0, (struct sockaddr*)&cli_temp, slen_temp);
        }else if (clients==1) {
        //new or existing
        if (client_port[0]==ntohs(cli_temp.sin_port)) {
            //send back to client 0 that nobody else connected yet
            sendto(sockfd, "You are the first client.", 24, 0, (struct sockaddr*)&cli_addr[0], slen[0]);
            printf("Only client\n");
        }else
        {
            //new connection
            cli_addr[1] = cli_temp;
            client_port[1] = ntohs(cli_addr[1].sin_port);
            clients++;
            printf("Second client\n");
            sendto(sockfd, buf, BUFLEN, 0, (struct sockaddr*)&cli_addr[0], slen[0]);
        }
        }else{
        //there are 2 clients connected here. If we get an error from the sendto then we decrement clients
        if (client_port[0]==ntohs(cli_temp.sin_port)) {
            //client 0 talking send to client 1
            printf("Sedning message to client 1\n");
            if (sendto(sockfd, buf, BUFLEN, 0, (struct sockaddr*)&cli_addr[1], slen[1])==-1)
            {
                clients--;
                err("sendto()");
            }
            }else {
            //client 1 talking send to client 0
            printf("Sending message to client 0\n");
            if (sendto(sockfd, buf, BUFLEN, 0, (struct sockaddr*)&cli_addr[0], slen[1])==-1)
            {
                clients--;
                err("sendto()");
            }
        }

    }
    /* Indicate listening for next utterance */
    //printf("\nTrainguard Terminal is hearing you ....\n");
    fflush(stdout);
    fflush(stderr);

    /* Wait data for next utterance */
    while ((k = cont_ad_read(cont, adbuf, 4096)) == 0)
    sleep_msec(100);

    if (k &lt; 0)
    E_FATAL("Failed to read audio\n");

    /*
    * Non-zero amount of data received; start recognition of new utterance.
    * NULL argument to uttproc_begin_utt =&gt; automatic generation of utterance-id.
    */
    if (ps_start_utt(ps, NULL) &lt; 0)
    E_FATAL("Failed to start utterance\n");
    ps_process_raw(ps, adbuf, k, FALSE, FALSE);
    //printf(" message - regarding the process begins \n");
    fflush(stdout);

    /* Note timestamp for this first block of data */
    ts = cont-&gt;read_ts;

    /* Decode utterance until end (marked by a "long" silence, &gt;1sec) */
    for (;;) {
        /* Read non-silence audio data, if any, from continuous listening module */
        if ((k = cont_ad_read(cont, adbuf, 4096)) &lt; 0)
        E_FATAL("Failed to read audio\n");
        if (k == 0) {
            /*
            * No speech data available; check current timestamp with most recent
            * speech to see if more than 1 sec elapsed.  If so, end of utterance.
            */
            if ((cont-&gt;read_ts - ts) &gt; DEFAULT_SAMPLES_PER_SEC / 4)
            break;
        }
        else {
            /* New speech data received; note current timestamp */
            ts = cont-&gt;read_ts;
        }

        /*
        * Decode whatever data was read above.
        */
        rem = ps_process_raw(ps, adbuf, k, FALSE, FALSE);

        /* If no work to be done, sleep a bit */
        if ((rem == 0) && (k == 0))
        sleep_msec(20);
    }

    /*
    * Utterance ended; flush any accumulated, unprocessed A/D data and stop
    * listening until current utterance completely decoded
    */
    ad_stop_rec(ad);
    while (ad_read(ad, adbuf, 4096) &gt;= 0);
    cont_ad_reset(cont);

    //printf("Processing...\n");
    fflush(stdout);
    /* Finish decoding, obtain and print result */
    ps_end_utt(ps);
    hyp = ps_get_hyp(ps, NULL, &uttid);
    //printf("%s: %s\n", uttid, hyp);
    fflush(stdout);
    /* Exit if the word spoken was "THATS ALL".  Change string in strcmp() for another phrase. */
    if (hyp) {
        sscanf(hyp, "%s", word);
        if (strcmp(hyp, "LASCHE FAHRPLAN") == 0 &&(token==500) ) {
            counter_correct = counter_correct + 1;
            printf("LASCHE FAHRPLAN   \n");
            printf("score %d/%s \n",counter_correct,uttid);
        }

    }

    /* Resume A/D recording for next utterance */
    if (ad_start_rec(ad) &lt; 0)
    E_FATAL("ad_start_rec failed\n");
}


cont_ad_close(cont);
close(sockfd);
}



// Code ends here
```

I have anothe server- client program which also contains a infinite loops. It accepts datas from Client A and sends them to Client B. It also sends specific Informations from Client B to Client A.

I want to combine both of them, so that It accepts datas from Client A and sends them to Client B and also sends specific Informations from Client B to Client A. Apart from that when specific commands are told, the message from Client A is to be modified and sent to Client B.

I combined both programs as they have common type of infinite loop, but although i communicate between Client A and Client B properly but my speech recognition doesnot give output anymore. :(

Can anyone suggest, How to run this two continuous based program parallely?

Comment: You're going to need to describe *how* you combined them. It's also important to state what operations can "block", and which cannot.

Comment: You should try and reduce your code to a minimal example. I *think* the correct answer would be to use sockets and ASIO, but the question is too broad.

Comment: You may waana checkout `select` and `poll` functions ans their usage!

Comment: @ams Please look the updated version

The speechrecognition whole code is [here](https://github.com/skerit/cmusphinx/blob/master/pocketsphinx/src/programs/continuous.c)

Comment: If you put the printf back in, do you see it print `"Trainguard Terminal is hearing you ...."`?

Comment: @ams No, it is not showing

Answer (score 1):

The first part of your loop uses `recvfrom` and `sendto` functions. These are *blocking* I/O functions. That is, they will not return until they have received or sent the data requested.

By putting both activities in the same loop you have ensured that only one speech activity can be performed for each incoming network read, and conversely, only one network transaction can occur for each speech session.

There are two solutions to this problem:

1. Use different threads, or processes, for each acitivity.
2. Use non-blocking I/O.

You can make the network code non-blocking by wrapping it all up in a big `if` statement that only runs if the `select` system call says a read would not block. You can make the speech input not block by adjusting the `cont_ad_read` loop, I would imagine (but have not checked).

However, if this activity is unrelated (i.e., one does not depend on the other) I would think that multiple threads would be the better option.

Comment: Thank you very much. client A and Client B should communicate with eachother.. only when a command is recognized, it should then modify some data and send it to client B. 

multiple thread? do you mean using posix/pthread concept? can you share a link where can i find a good example of threading in sockets? 

Thanks again

Comment: Sharing data between threads is easy enough -- you just need to be careful with locking. There's a good place with lots of examples [here](http://stackoverflow.com/search). ;-)